# Is it possible to customize the release ID when deploying to Docker container registry in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

Context: I've recently switched a Heroku app from deploying with Git using a Heroku stack + multiple buildpacks to [deploying multiple Docker images using the Heroku Container Registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime), pushing the images from the CI build (I did this in order to achieve faster deployment).

The problem is that now the button `Compare diff` doesn't work anymore, because the release IDs are not following the Git commit hashes anymore, but are given automatically generated names by Herroku:

[image: deployment activity showing automated release identification]

If only there was a way to override these release IDs, I could override them to be the commit hash from the CI build. However, I couldn't find a way to do that in Heroku documentation.

Has anyone else ran into this same problem and found a way to workaround it?

Comment: Ran into the same issue when moving to Heroku containers